# How to get value of variable outside child process that i store in variable in child process?

Tags: c, linux

i am storing data in variable in child process and when i get value outside child process it returns me garbage value. But when i get value of variable (that i stored in the variable in the child process) in the child process it gives me correct value.
My code is given below. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void getValues();
void printValues();

int main()
{
int cpid, i = 0, j = 0, mat1[4], mat2[4], mat3[4], mat4[4], mat[4], sum1[4], sum2[4];
//get values in all matrixes.
for(i=0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter value %d in matrix 1: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &mat1[i]);
    }

    for(i=0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter value %d in matrix 2: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &mat2[i]);
    }

for(i=0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter value %d in matrix 3: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &mat3[i]);
    }

    for(i=0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter value %d in matrix 4: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &mat4[i]);
    }
 //print values of all matrixes.
printf("\nMatrix 1:\n");
    for(i=0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", mat1[i]);
        if(i == 1)
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    printf("\n\nMatrix 2:\n");
    for(i=0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", mat2[i]);
        if(i == 1)
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    printf("\n\nMatrix 3:\n");
    for(i=0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", mat3[i]);
        if(i == 1)
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    printf("\n\nMatrix 4:\n");
    for(i=0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", mat4[i]);
        if(i == 1)
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

cpid = fork();

if(cpid < 0)
{
    printf("\n\nFaild!\n\n");
}
if(cpid == 0)
{
    for(i=0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        sum1[i] = mat1[i] + mat2[i];
    }
}
else
{
    for(i = 0; i <=10000; i++)
    {for(j = 0; j<=10000; j++){}}

for(i=0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        sum2[i] = mat3[i] + mat4[i];
    }

for(i=0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        mat[i] = sum1[i] + sum2[i];
    }

printf("\nSum of All Matrixes:\n");
    for(i=0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", mat[i]);
        if(i == 1)
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Why are you expecting that the parent should be able to see the modified variables of the child?

Comment: you mean parent is not able to see the modified variables?

Comment: Yes, it's a basic principle that stems from the isolation of processes. Use shared memory in case you really want to go around this.

Comment: please tell me how can i use shared memory.

Comment: You really need to grasp a few operating system concepts before diving into shared memory :-)

Answer (score -1):

You seem to be confused about how processes work. When a parent forks a child that child has a copy of the parent's address space(heap & stack). However, after that point they exist as separate entities; any changes to the address space in the child isn't reflected in the parent's address space and vice versa. The only way to share resources between processes is either via inter-process communication API's in the OS(nasty performance losses due to constant system interrupts) or shared memory segments(via mmap or shmem). Because of this you are mostly likely going to want to use threads instead of processes; a great resource for learning about threads can be found here: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/ .

A rough example on how your specified query could be done is shown below(not really sure what you are trying to achieve with the actual code, but nonetheless.):

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int size;
    int matrix[];
} MatrixStruct;

void *thread_matrix_calc(void *arg) {
    //Cast arg to the struct it points at
    MatrixStruct *matrix = (MatrixStruct *)arg;

    //Pull variables from that struct
    int matrix_size = matrix->size;
    int (*matrix_arry)[matrix_size] = matrix->matrix;

    /*
     * Code for child matrix manipulation goes here...
     */

     return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    //Initialize all matrices and summations 
    MatrixStruct *child_matrix = malloc(sizeof(int) + (MATRIX_SIZE * sizeof(int));

    //Initialize and start child thread
    pthread_t child_thread;
    int child_thread_init = pthread_create(&child_thread, NULL, &thread_matrix_calc, (void *)child_matrix);

    //Ensure initialization was successful
    if(child_thread_init < 0) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    /*
     * Code for parent matrix manipulation goes here...
     */

    //Join child thread to ensure child has finished manipulating it's matrix.
    pthread_join(child_thread, NULL);

    /*
     * At this point both the parent and child manipulated matrices can be accessed 
     * in the remaining thread.
     */

    return 0;
}
```

> Note: code wasn't compiled and is given only as a semantical demonstration of POSIX threads.